# Want to enable GZip compression in Weblogic

Tags: compression, webserver, weblogic

I want to enable GZIP compression for my static file like css styles, javascript which is serving from weblogic server. Can anyone help to how to configure this feature in weblogic server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/ to download it and update your *web.xml* file with the following config:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CompressingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param><param-name>includeContentTypes</param-name><param-value>text/html,text/css,application/x-javascript</param-value></init-param>
    <init-param><param-name>compressionThreshold</param-name><param-value>256</param-value></init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7):

## Configure GZIP compression for Web applications

You can enable and configure content-encoding GZIP compression at the domain level or Web application level. Values for a specific Web application override domain-level values.
To configure GZIP compression for all Web applications in the domain:

1. If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the
   Administration Console, click **Lock & Edit** ([see Use the Change
   Center](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/console/UseTheChangeCenter.html)).
2. In the Domain Structure tree, select your domain.
3. Select **Configuration > Web Applications**.
4. Define the following domain-wide Web application configuration settings for
   GZIP compression:

   - **GZIP Compression Enabled**: enable or disable GZIP compression for all Web applications. By default, this value is not enabled.
   - **GZIP Compression Min. Content Length**: configure the minimum content length to trigger GZIP compression. The default value is 2048.
   - **GZIP Compression Content Type**: configure the type of content to be included in compression. The default value is text/html, text/xml, text/plain. Click Save to save any changes.
5. To activate these changes, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click **Activate Changes**.
   Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart ([see Use the Change Center](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/console/UseTheChangeCenter.html)).

Comment: Extra content types I use including the defaults: 
text/html
text/xml
text/plain
text/css
application/xml
application/xhtml+xml
application/rss+xml
application/javascript
application/x-javascript

Comment: How can I test this? I can see if I activate this that my response has an extra response header `X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip` but the content is still json. I am expecting the content to be scrambled of some sort? I changed the Content Length to 0 and 1 and made my response very big but still it does not look like it compress anything.