# Best way to use gzip compression for css, js, images files in weblogic server

Tags: java, gzip

Can any one please let me know how to configure the gzip compression of js/css/image files of j2ee application in weblogic? I am totally confused..with lot of options..

Comment: Purchase an Oracle support contract, that will get you 25% of the way there j/k

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742883/want-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-weblogic