# enable gzip compression on weblogic 11g

Tags: oracle11g, gzip, weblogic11g

I need to enable gzip compression on oracle 11g and tried with this
[Want to enable GZip compression in Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742883/want-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-weblogic)
but in oracle 11g don't appear that menu item, somebody know where is the option in weblogic 11g I search in the console but I can't found it, or is there other way to resolve it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration came just for 12c, you won't find it anywhere in 11g.

AFAIK, the most common way to accomplish compression in 11g is deploying a servlet filter. Please check this project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/

Hope it works for you.